# Midrash About God Repeating Words of Torah

Tags: sources-mekorot, torah-study, midrash

I am drawing a blank as to the source of this midrash, that when a person learns Torah, at the same time God is learning that same section, or that He repeats what the person said?

(Hopefully I am not mistaken and this is a real midrash!)

Any help in locating the source would be appreciated!

Comment: https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=D50yo51zKE4C&pg=PA184&lpg=PA184&dq=that+when+a+person+learns+Torah,+at+the+same+time+God+is+learning&source=bl&ots=lswgNKjxO_&sig=p8W8n7ZNVTt-eTMH4jJ_n8CY15w&hl=en&sa=X&ei=f69cVdmYLc3Y7AbZi4GYDw&ved=0CD4Q6AEwBQ#v=onepage&q=that%20when%20a%20person%20learns%20Torah%2C%20at%20the%20same%20time%20God%20is%20learning&f=false

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya, Evan!

Comment: Reb Tzadok of Lublin said "When you think of H', He is thinking of you"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is found in Tanna Devei Eliyahu Rabba, [beginning of chapter 18](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49591&st=&pgnum=56&hilite=) and Yalkut Shamoni Eicha [1034](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9758&st=&pgnum=376&hilite=).

The Tanna Devei Eliyahu version is:

> מאי שפכי כמים לבך נוכח פני ה' מכאן אמרו כל ת"ח שיושב וקורא ושונה ועוסק בתורה הקב"ה יושב כנגדו וקורא ושונה עמו
>
> What does "[Poor out your heart like water opposite the face of Hashem](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/16458/jewish/Chapter-2.htm#showrashi=true&v=19)" mean? From here they said that every Torah scholar that sits and reads and repeats and learns Torah, Hashem sits opposite him and read and repeats with him.

It then goes on to demonstrate that נכח - which I translated as opposite - means face to face.